# Not being able to use empty wrapper <> in reactJS

Tags: reactjs

[image]

as suggested in [aboutfunction](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn#writing-markup-with-jsx) I tried using an empty wrapper <>...</> wrapper but error is being thrown as  Unexpected token for <> ..please help in error resolution

```js
const rootx = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('Abt'));
const element5 = <AboutPage />; 
rootx.render(element5); 

function AboutPage() {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>About</h1>
      <p>Hello there.<br />How do you do?</p>
    </>
  );
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Add React in One Minute</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <h2>Add React in One Minute</h2>
    
    <!-- We will put our React component inside this div. -->

<link rel="icon" type="./x-icon" href="./favicon.ico">


<div id="Abt"></div>
    <!-- Load React. -->
    <!-- Note: when deploying, replace "development.js" with "production.min.js". -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
  <!-- Load your React component. -->
 <script type="module" src="lik.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is your babel configuration?

Comment: attached screenshot ..error is got while preprocessing jsx files using cmd : npx babel --watch src1 --out-dir . --presets react-app/prod

Comment: Konrad I just preprocess jsx as suggested in react docs using the command: npx babel --watch src1 --out-dir . --presets react-app/prod   .folder src1 contains the jsx

Comment: 6.26.0 (babel-core 6.26.3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const root4 = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('Abt'));
const element4 = <AboutPage />; 
root4.render(element4); 

function AboutPage() {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>About</h1>
      <p>Hello there.<br />How do you do?</p>
    </>
  );
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Test Page-React</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <h2>Add React in One Minute</h2>
    
    <!-- We will put our React component inside this div. -->
    <div id="root"></div>
    <div id="tworoot"></div>
<link rel="icon" type="./x-icon" href="./favicon.ico">

<div id="Abt"></div>
    <!-- Load  React. -->
    <!-- Note: when deploying, replace "development.js" with "production.min.js". -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
  <!-- Load your React component. -->
 <script type="module" src="lik.js"></script>

  
  </body>
</html>
```

new version of babel can be updated via step 2 of [babel version update](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/add-react-to-a-website#add-jsx-to-a-project)

> npm install @babel/cli@7 babel-preset-react-app@10

and updated new JSX preprocessor command :

> npx babel --watch src --out-dir . --presets babel-preset-react-app/prod

this will allow the empty<>..</> to compile and render (attached screenshot)[image: about]